# Symfony 3, Xdebug and NetBeans 10 config

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, xdebug

I have to move from developing my Symfony 3 app on PhpStorm to NetBeans.  However I cannot seem to get the app to debug.  Below is my configuration - any advice on where I am going wrong will be appreciated.

Current status:

php.ini setup:

```
zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

PHP built-in server running with command:

```
php bin/console server:run
```

Firefox extension installed and enabled for "Debug" with a key of "netbeans-xdebug" (PhpStorm would capture this as well when set to "listen").

I open the page below and it loads correctly:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Opening NetBeans and confirm project "Run Configuration" set to:

- Run As: Local Web Site
- Project URL: http://localhost:8000/
- ... and in the "Advanced" config:

  - Debug URL: Default http://localhost:8000/
  - No Path Mapping

Start the debugger in NetBeans (Debug Project toolbar button).  Status bar shows "Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)".

I set a breakpoint in one of my controllers for my Symfony 3 project and then load that URL.  The breakpoint is not hit, the page loads successfully and "Waiting For Connection" remains in the status bar.

I'm at a loss!  Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Happy to provide more information as required.